# Java Generics erasure in Multimaps

Tags: java, generics, guava

I have two `Multimap`s of `String`s indexed by (i) `Integer`s and (ii) `Double`s and a routine to output lists of the `String`s.

```
public static void outputInteger(Multimap<Integer, String> map) {
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        Collection<String> strings = map.get(key);
        output(strings);
    }
}

public static void outputDouble(Multimap<Double, String> map) {
    for (Double key : map.keySet()) {
        Collection<String> strings = map.get(key);
        output(strings);
    }
}
```

I would like to combine these into a single routine using `Number` as the superclass of `Integer` and `Double`

```
public static void outputNumber(Multimap<? extends Number, String> map) {
    for (Number key : map.keySet()) {
        Collection<String> ids = map.get(key); //** 
    }
}
```

but the asterisked line does not compile

```
The method get(capture#5-of ? extends Number) in the type 
Multimap<capture#5-of ? extends Number,String> is not 
applicable for the arguments (Number)
```

How do I tackle this?

Comment: map.get(key) won't it give you a 'String' rather than Collection<String> ?

Comment: @prashantsunkari I would expect it to behave similarly to the examples above. It's a Guava Multimap

Comment: @prashantsunkari As this is Multimap will result with collection.

Comment: Thanks guys! I missed that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static void output(Multimap<? extends Number, String> map) {
    for (Collection<String> strings : map.asMap().values()) {
        output(strings);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This definitely circumvents the issue and is more correct anyway.

Comment: Could even just be `Multimap<?, String>` given what's being done there.

Answer (score 9):

The declaration

```
Multimap<? extends Number, String> map;
```

indicates that map has a key type that is an *unknown but specific subtype (inclusive) of Number*. In other words, the compiler thinks it could be a `Multimap<Integer, String>`, or `Multimap<Short, String>`, or `Multimap<Number, String>`, etc.  For this reason you can't call `map.get(Number)`, because as far as the compiler knows, it could be a `Multimap<Double, String>`.

The reason this can't be done is more evident with `put`.  Should you be able to do `put(Number, String)` on `map`?  No, because if it happened to be a `Multimap<Integer, String>`, you could then add a `Double` key which will then have violated the integrity of the map.

With the normal `Map<K, V>` interface, this isn't a problem as `get` is defined as `get(Object)`, not `get(K)`.

Paul's answer has a great workaround to this situation.  Essentially he is using an intermediate generic method to give the unknown type (in this case represented by `capture#5-of ? extends Number`) a name (the type parameter `T`).  This allows you to associate the captures occurring in two different contexts so that you can do something across those contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination but I am confused when you say "specific subtype of Number" and don't mention Double. Isn't Double also a subtype of Number along with Integer, Short, Number

Comment: @prashantsunkari: I wasn't about to list all of the subtypes, there are many.  That's why I said "etc".  Yes, `Double` is another possibility.

Comment: so shouldn't your statement "because as far as the compiler knows, it's a Multimap<Double, String>."  should be "because as far as the compiler knows, it can be any one of a Multimap<Double, String> or Multimap<Integer, String> or etc"

Comment: @prashantsunkari: That was meant to be read as "as far as the compiler knows, it could be..."  I've changed the wording.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) to achieve what you want:

```
public static <T extends Number> void outputNumber(Multimap<T, String> map) {
    for (T key : map.keySet()) {
        Collection<String> strings = map.get(key);
        output(strings);
    }
}
```

The reason it doesn't work with a wildcard is because `? extends Number` means *some unknown type* that is or extends `Number`. Meanwhile, `Number key` could reference some other, incompatible type (for all the compiler knows).

Comment: I appreciated this approach and it works but I find the signature that Louis uses easier to remember (and I should use the values rather than the keys)

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: Indeed, Louis' answer is a great solution to this specific issue (it's more correct and more efficient) whereas Paul's approach addresses the more general case (based on the assumption that your code was more of a strawman).

Comment: @Mark understood. Actually I may use Paul's solution as I need the key as well. The code was real but the classes Double/Integer were for illustration.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: If you need the key and the collection of values, Louis' approach is still a good one, just iterate over `entrySet()` instead of `values()`.

Comment: Struggling! I wrote  `public static List<List<String>> test2(Multimap<? extends Number, String> map) {
  for (Map.Entry entry : map.asMap().entrySet()) {
  }
 }` but it complains that Map.Entry must be parameterised and I can't work out how. (`Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>` doesn't seem to be allowed

Comment: @peter.murray.rust That would need to be `Map.Entry<? extends Number, Collection<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not pass the generic argument but declare it.

If you have this type of implementation the error would not occur

```
public static <T extends Number> void outputNumber(Multimap<T, String> map) {

        for (T key : map.keySet()) {
            map.get(key);
        }
    }
```